# Java coin change outputting weird values [Not homework]

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my coin change algorithm to work... but it's outputting weird results...
It's supposed to enumerate all permutations of change to be given for input amount of cents.

input of 27 cents, `printValues(dan.makeChange(27));`  gets me:

`[[3, 300, 1386, 4720], [3, 300, 1386, 4720], [3, 300, 1386, 4720],etc...`

input of 7 cents gets me:

`[[0, 0, 3, 10], [0, 0, 3, 10], [0, 0, 3, 10], [0, 0, 3, 10]]`

**Code:**

```
public List<int[]> makeChange(int change) {
    List<int[]> resultsList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    resultsList = changeMaker(change, new int[] {0,0,0,0}, resultsList);
    return resultsList;
}

public List<int[]> changeMaker(int change, int[] toAdd, List<int[]> resultsList) {               
    if (change == 0) {
        //if no $, return the list...
        resultsList.add(toAdd);
        return resultsList;
    }
    int[] coins = {25, 10, 5, 1};
    for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
        if (coins[i] <= change) {
            //temp = {0, 0, 0, 0}
            int[] temp = toAdd;
            //move to next amount in temp array
            temp[i]++;
            resultsList = changeMaker(change-coins[i], temp, resultsList);
        }
    }
    return resultsList;
}
```

Call:

```
    printValues(dan.makeChange(27));            
}
public void printValues (List<int[]> results) {
    List<String> printable = new ArrayList<String> ();

    for (int[] array : results) {
        printable.add(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
    System.out.println(printable);
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Run it with a debugger, see where it differs from the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you wanted to copy the array with this line:

```
int[] temp = toAdd;
```

However, to create a copy, you have to do this:

```
int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(toAdd, toAdd.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! The output seems correct now, but some of the arrays are repeating, Here's some output... `[[1, 0, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1, 2], [0, 2, 0, 7],etc...` you can see that the `[0, 2, 1, 2]` permutation is repeated. Why is that?